# OCaml is printing one extra value

Tags: ocaml

so i am currently coding in OCaml and im supposed to print all even numbers using a function provided to me. For some reason when i input [1;2;3;4;5] my output is [2;4;5] instead of [2;4]. does anyone know why?
the code below is the match statement to concatenate the even numbers.

```
let rec rem x n = match x with
|[]->[]
|[h]->[h]
|(h)::t-> if n(h) = false then h:: rem t n else rem t n;;
```

Comment: Please show the whole function, as well as `n`'s definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matcher `| [h] -> [h]` will always return the last element.. even if it's odd (you don't run the check on it).  Should be something like `| [h] -> if n(h) = false then [h] else []` (maybe reversed logic since I'm not sure exactly what `n` is doing).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the

```
| [h] ->[h]
```

line.
In your example, when you reach

```
| 4::[5] -> if n(4) = false then 4 :: rem [5] n else rem [5] n
```

you will then enter the

```
| [5] -> [5]
```

which doesn't check for `!n(5)`.
Your pattern match is already complete without it (ocaml would complain otherwise anyway), because

```
| 5::[] -> ...
```

catches the "last element"/"single element list" cases.